# How to export termstore

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, term-store

I've a termstore with a lot of entries and in treeview.
I've to export it to import then in an other site.

I've tried this script but i loose the tree and i can't import it, everything is on the same level

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url=Read-Host "Entrez l'url du site sharepoint"
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite $url
$web = Get-SPWeb($url)
$termSet = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $url
$termStore = $termSet.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
#récupère le term set du groupe Finance
$termGroup = $termStore.Groups["Finance"]

# File and Directory Location
$dirLocation = "C:\tmp\Terms\"

#New-Item ($dirLocation) -Type Directory | Out-Null
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter(($dirLocation) + "Terms.csv")
#"Term Name,Id,Owner,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate" | Out-File $path
[Byte[]] $amp = 0xEF,0xBC,0x86

# CSV headers
$file.Writeline("Term Name,Id,Owner,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate")


foreach ($termGroups in $termGroup.TermSets)
{
    foreach ($term in $termGroups.GetAllTerms()) 
    {
        #getNode $termSets

            [Byte[]] $amp = 0xEF,0xBC,0x86
            $file.Writeline("""" + $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&") + """" + "," + $term.Id + "," + $term.Owner + "," + $term.CreatedDate + "," + $term.LastModifiedDate)
            #$term.Name+ "," + $term.Id + "," + $term.Owner + "," + $term.CreatedDate + "," + $term.LastModifiedDate | Out-File $path - Append

    }
}
$file.Flush()
$file.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i did to have a treeview.
Certainly not the best method but a working solution

```
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url=Read-Host "Entrez l'url du site sharepoint"
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite $url
$web = Get-SPWeb($url)
$termSet = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $url
$termStore = $termSet.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
#récupère le term set du groupe Finance
$termGroup = $termStore.Groups["Categories"]

# File and Directory Location
$dirLocation = "C:\tmp\Terms\"

#New-Item ($dirLocation) -Type Directory | Out-Null
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter(($dirLocation) + "Terms.csv")
#"Term Name,Id,Owner,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate" | Out-File $path
[Byte[]] $amp = 0xEF,0xBC,0x86

# CSV headers
$file.Writeline("Term Set Name,Term Set Description, LCID, Available for tagging,Parent1,Parent2,Parent3,Parent4,Parent5,Parent6,Id,Owner,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate")


foreach ($termGroups in $termGroup.TermSets)
{
    foreach ($term in $termGroups.GetAllTerms()) 
    {
        #getNode $termSets
        $i = 0
        $parent = ""
        $termParent = $term.Parent
        while($i -le 6)
        {

            if($termParent.Id -ne $null)
            {
                $parent += """"+$termParent.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")+""""
            }
            else
            {
                break
            }
            $parent += ","
            $termParent = $termParent.Parent
            $i++
        }
        $test = $parent.split(",")
        [array]::Reverse($test)
        $parent = $test -join ','
        $parent += """"+$term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&")+""""
        $cpt = $test.Length
        while($cpt -le 6)
        {
            $parent += ","
            $cpt++
        }

            [Byte[]] $amp = 0xEF,0xBC,0x86
            $file.Writeline("""" + $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&") + """" + "," +"""" + $term.Name.Replace([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($amp), "&") + """" + ",,TRUE," + $term.LastModifiedDate+$parent + $parent + "," + $term.Id + "," + $term.Owner + "," + $term.CreatedDate )
    }
}
$file.Flush()
$file.Close()
```